# Less formal synonym for "Confirmed", "Acknowledged"

Tags: synonyms, formality

I'm looking for a less formal synonym for "Confirmed" or "Ackowledged", that retains some brevity.  As an example, say I've received an e-mail from my manager asking me to switch to a different task.  The request is clear, and I'd like to acknowledge that I've read and understood it, but I don't need even that much vebosity.  I could reply with just "Roger" but that just seems almost too informal:

> "We've got clearance, Clarence."
>
> "Roger, Roger."
>
> "What's our vector, Victor?"

Comment: Gotcha? Ok? Hokey-dokey? kthxbi?

Comment: "kthxbi" to my manager would certainly capture the "less formal" aspect I asked for.

Comment: "gotcha" "got it" "okay" "sounds good" "deal"

Comment: "Check", "OK" are brief

Comment: Righty-ho! Okey-dokey! Sure thing! Will do! No problem! (No probs, np, no problemo)

Comment: There are some decent suggestions there.  While I can upvote your comments, I can't Accept any of them.  :)

Comment: "Will do"; "Proceeding". Imho confirmed and acknowledged are not formal at all; just plain words.

Comment: Yup. Ack. OK. Agreed. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might just say:

> Understood, thanks.

This leaves unstated the fact that you will actually execute the request, but unless your manager is especially paranoid, it's probably okay to leave that implicit. The "thanks" is just sugar to sweeten the response a bit and keep things collegial.

Answer (score 1):

In the British Navy, **aye-aye** means ¨Heard and understood and I will obey¨ (and saying ¨Yes¨ to anything other than a **Yes or No?** question or a pleasant observation will get you in trouble).  It has some swash, so isn´t too formal but can hardly be called informal since it is naval protocol ;)

Depending on your relationship with your manager (and on your manager´s sense of humour), you may want to use the full ¨Aye-aye, *sir*!¨

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> Will do! Thanks.

I use it all the time!

Answer (score 0):

> "Hi ____
>
> Ok I'll start the ___ now
>
> Regards,"

Keep it simple, silly. KISS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

> Wilco.

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wilco) defines **wilco** as:

> Expressing compliance or agreement, especially acceptance of instructions received by radio.
>
> *"Wilco, Sir," came the reply*